# how to perform addition in Node Js?

Tags: node.js, addition

This is my code

```
const calculator = (req, res) => {
    let option = req.body.option
    let num1 = req.body.num1
    let num2 = req.body.num2
    //console.log(num1 + num2)

    if (option == '+') {
        res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            result: num1 + num2
        })
    }
}

module.exports = { calculator }
```

I am trying to add num1 and num2,
for eg num1 = 2 and num2 = 2
expected result should be 'result: 4'

but instead of result: 4 I am getting result: 22

Comment: How are you making the request? Seems like the numbers are being sent as a string. Please send your code for that.

Comment: First, you should check if this question has already been answered, second, you have to convert values into numbers before performing addition.

Comment: @asportnoy Thankss numbers were being sent as a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is because both variable are 'string' when you get from request.

Use this as result

```
result: Number(num1) + Number(num2)
```

Ref: [Number()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number)

Answer (score 0):

Or shorter

```
            result: +num1 + +num2
```

as `+'2'` for js engine is equivalent to `Number('2')`

Answer (score -1):

```js
const req = {
  body: {
    num1: '1',
    num2: '2'
  }
};

const num1 = parseInt(req.body.num1);
const num2 = parseInt(req.body.num2);

console.log('sum:', num1 + num2);
```

That's because num1 and num2 are strings. You propably get the values from and input field which always translates anything entered to a string.

Just do

```
 let num1 = parseInt(req.body.num1)
 let num2 = parseInt(req.body.num2)
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: This won't work with decimal numbers. You should use `Number()` instead.

Comment: True, and Number doesn't work with comma separated European decimals (returning NaN) either. It depends on the actual use case.

For the given example parseInt does the job.

Comment: It is not w0rking.

Comment: Yes, it is. I've inserted a code snippet.